# Remove permission on a folder by csom

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, csom, folder, remote-event-receiver

My scenario is i have 2 lists: company and domestic

whenever i create a new company a remote event receiver fires and create a folder in domestic.now when am trying to update an item in  company,i added another event receiver to replicate the change to the folder in domestic.

I am having some issues with updating item:

1. By code am reading the value of the folder name in the edit form page which am using 
   to get the folder object in domestic list. BUT obviosly it tell me the
   folder doesnt exist because the name hasnt been updated yet in domestic list.
2. IF the above is solved i want to know how to remove all users having  permission on that folder

some code snippets:

```
string folderSetUrl = CompanyType + "/" + CompanyName;



Folder companyfolder = clientContext.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderSetUrl);
                    companyfolder.ListItemAllFields.ResetRoleInheritance();
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this worked in my scenario.

```
List companylibrary = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(CompanyType);
                Web site = clientContext.Web;
                companylibrary.BreakRoleInheritance(true, false);
                clientContext.Load(site, s => s.RoleDefinitions);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                clientContext.Load(companylibrary, l => l.HasUniqueRoleAssignments);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                if (companylibrary.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
                {
                    RoleAssignmentCollection oRoleAssignments = companylibrary.RoleAssignments;
                    clientContext.Load(oRoleAssignments);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    foreach (RoleAssignment oRoleAssignment in oRoleAssignments)
                    {
                        clientContext.Load(oRoleAssignment, r => r.Member, r => r.RoleDefinitionBindings);
                        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                        Principal oPrincipal = oRoleAssignment.Member;
                        if (oPrincipal.PrincipalType == Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.PrincipalType.User)
                        {
                            foreach (RoleDefinition rd in oRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
                            {
                                //if (rd.RoleTypeKind == RoleType.Guest)
                                //{
                                clientContext.Load(rd); oRoleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Remove(rd);
                                oRoleAssignment.Update();
                                clientContext.Load(oRoleAssignment, r => r.Member, r => r.RoleDefinitionBindings);
                                companylibrary.Update();
                                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                                //}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this to break role inheritance and remove all permissions.

```
//method defined by CSOM
public virtual void BreakRoleInheritance(bool copyRoleAssignments, bool clearSubscopes);

//it's use
companyfolder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance(false, false);
companyfolder.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: doesnt work,have a look at my answer